# How to fill a vue-chartjs from a http call vue 3 composition API

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I must show a graph, using vue 3 and composition API, with which I must fill a dataset with the data I bring from an http call, if I fill the dataset with static data the table is displayed correctly but if I fill it with the data brought from the call it is empty, I have tried to use the reactive variable and the watch method but apparently I am not implementing it correctly, I share the Any idea of how I can implement the watch method or a reactive property so that the graph is updated dynamically?:

```
<script lang="ts" setup>
import axios from 'axios'
import { onMounted, onUnmounted, reactive, watch } from 'vue'
import {
  Chart as ChartJS, 
  Title,
  Tooltip, 
  Legend,
  BarElement,
  CategoryScale,
  LinearScale
} from 'chart.js'
import { Bar } from 'vue-chartjs'

const cpu = {
  labels: [''],
  datasets: [
    { 
      label: 'Consumo',    
      backgroundColor: '#f87979',    
      barThickness: 40,    
      borderRadius: 5,    
      data: [0]    
    }

  ]

}


ChartJS.register(CategoryScale, LinearScale, BarElement, Title, Tooltip, Legend)


const urlGraficas: string =

  import.meta.env.VITE_APP_ROOT_API + import.meta.env.VITE_BACKEND_DASHBOARD_DESA + '/graficas'       
async function pedirGraficas()     
  const responseGraficaCpu = await axios.get<any>(urlGraficas + 'Cpu')    
  console.log(responseGraficaCpu.data)    
  responseGraficaCpu.data.forEach((element: { cuando: string; usu: string; cpu: number }) => {    
    cpu.labels.push(element.cuando)    
    cpu.datasets[0].data.push(element.cpu)    
  })    
  cpu.labels.shift()    
  cpu.datasets[0].data.shift()        
}        
watch(    
  () => cpu,    
  async () => {    
    await pedirGraficas()    
  }    
)        
const io = {    
  labels: [    
    'Enero',    
    'Febrero',    
    'Marzo',    
    'Abril',    
    'Mayo',    
    'Junio',    
    'Julio',    
    'Augosto',    
    'Septiembre',    
    'Octubre',    
    'Noviembre',    
    'Deciembre'    
  ],    
  datasets: [    
    {    
      label: 'Consumo',    
      backgroundColor: '#f87979',    
      barThickness: 40,    
      borderRadius: 5,    
      data: [5, 27, 63, 32, 71, 40, 39, 40, 2, 19, 12, 38]    
    }    
  ]    
}    

const options = { 
  responsive: true,    
  maintainAspectRatio: true    
}        
onMounted(async () => {    
  await pedirGraficas()      
})    

let graficas: Element[] = reactive([])    

</script>
```